# Wordpress Changing move sidebar to left

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

im trying to move the sidebar to the left on this website:
https://www.goodietravel.com/

I tried:

```
.widget-area{
   float:left;
 }
```

dosent work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need any css settings.
Just move your sidebar codes which start with `<aside id="secondary" ..>`
on the `<div id="primary"...>`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNSlW.png)